# using xsd.exe to generate c# files from ereg association

Tags: c#, xsd

I am trying to convert the [XSD](https://www.ereg-association.eu/media/1731/version-13-initialvehicleinformation.xsd) to some C# classes.  I've done this with plenty of other files, but I am wondering why this one is not working.

The [schema information](https://www.ereg-association.eu/topic-groups/topic-group-xii/) contains a link in the download section to [the XSD file](https://www.ereg-association.eu/media/1731/version-13-initialvehicleinformation.xsd) which I've downloaded to my local disk. Then ran the XSD command from the ms dev tools.

This is the dump from the command prompt:

```
C:\temp\XSD>xsd version-13-draft-ivi-xsd-scheme.xsd /classes  /namespace:MyNamespace
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig:Signature' element is not declared. Line 17, position 5.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'version-13-draft-ivi-xsd-scheme'.
- The element 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
```

It seems like the XSD validator can not download the signature namespace.  But I an not sure what exactly is happening.  Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: `schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"` is referencing a local file called `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd`. Does that exist in your working directory? See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd to your local directory, and add it as another parameter to your command:

```
xsd version-13-draft-ivi-xsd-scheme.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd /Classes
```

The xsd you are wanting to import contains a reference to that file, on line 7:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
```

Comment: if you put the xsd files in the reversed order, it's not working... i don't get it.  But it works.  thanks.